# Lighthouse Report - Uses passive listeners to improve scrolling performance

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My angular app report show [this advice](https://snag.gy/3rBZJE.jpg) about use of passive listener.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you clicked the 'learn more' link? Pretty sure that answers your question.

Comment: Yes, here's the [link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/passive-event-listeners). I think angular does not support the 'passive' option.